# How to set Neovim+SpaceVim to syntax highlight Hugo (markdown, TOML, Go+HTML, CSS) files?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, hugo, neovim, vim-syntax-highlighting, spacevim

I am on Manjaro using Neovim and SpaceVim vanilla installations. The editor works fantastically well.

Since I am new to vim-style editing, I do not want to mess my configuration. Yet I'm not very savvy about how to add plugins to Neovim+SpaceVim.

I want my Hugo files to have a proper syntax highlighting. Files's content are TOML (.toml), markdown (.md, but not .markdown), Go+HTML (.html with some Go templates inside) and CSS (.css).

I tried to use the `vim-go` plugin using `yay` package manager, but there was no syntax highlighting :(

If you could help me, please take into account that I'm very new to this vim-universe. Thanks!

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rob, you commented me to post this question in vi.stackexchange.com… Do I have to do it or I can leave it here? Because there are many questions already answered here about neovim…

Comment: You can leave it here. Parts of your question could probably be better over there, though

Comment: Yes, it is a complex issue, with more than one technology involved. I can repeat it over there, if that doesn't mean to downgrade my reputation ;D

Comment: Don't do that! Cross posting is not allowed.

Comment: That's why I asked first. I had the notion it is a bad thing. I keep it here. I suppose more people aware of Hugo are around here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241096/discussion-between-lobaluna-and-rob).